# Tensorflow does not detect GPU - lambdalabs

Tags: nvidia, python, gpu, tensorflow

I try to get tensorflow GPU up and running in a virtual environment (venv):

I use lambdalabs
OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I have following python script: checkGPY.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

Outside the venv it works fine. I obtain Default GPU Device: /device:GPU:0.
If a train a small neural network (NN) and `watch nvidia-smi` I see that the GPU memory increases during training. So the GPU resources are used for NN training.

However if I run it is inside a venv (I installed tensorflow version: 2.6.0 inside the venv.)

`(venv) x@y $ python checkGPU.py`

I obtain: Please install GPU version of TF

I obtain also following: Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So I understand that the dynamic library libcudnn.so.8 cannot be accessed from inside the venv.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I follow the instructions written on [Tensorflow in venv using lambdalabs](https://deeptalk.lambdalabs.com/t/tensorflow-does-not-detect-gpu/2375)